# IF columns in X are FALSE, drop the same columns in Y?

Tags: r

Trying to have specific columns within a logical vector (X) communicate with the same columns in a character vector (Y), so that if any columns in the logical vector are FALSE then those same columns in the character vector will drop.

```
> X[1:5]
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

```
> Y[1:5]
[1] "Cats" "Dogs" "Fish" "Mice" "Bird"
```

The reason why I don't just manually "Boolean" the characters in Y is because they're not fixed and are web-scraped from inconsistent sources. So for my particular situation, X has to logically determine the fate of Y.

I tried this dodgy `if` statement with no luck.

```
if(X[1:5] == FALSE){rm(Y[1:5])}
```

This is my desired end goal:

```
> Y
[1] "Dogs" "Fish" "Bird"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you can subset vector (1) using position, eg `Y[1:2]` to take first two elements from `Y`, or (2) using a logical vector to index the elements we want. For your problem, you might use second solution.

```
Y[X]
# that similar to [c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]

# [1] "Dogs" "Fish" "Bird"
```

**data**

```
X <- c(FALSE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE)
Y <- c("Cats", "Dogs", "Fish", "Mice", "Bird")
```